# Python で動的に変数を使いたいのですが、無理なのでしょうか。

Tags: python, django

非エンジニアの素人です。質問が分かりにくければすみません。

Python DjangoフレームワークでWEBアプリ作成にチャレンジしています。
Views.py内で同じ内容をユーザーごとに何度も書くのが面倒なので、for文でユーザーリストから簡単に作りたいなと思い、ググりながらようやく以下のようなコードを作りました。

```
llist = ['tour','som','aim']
for p in llist:
    code = '{} = Eva_{}.objects.all()'.format(p,p)
    exec(code)
    code2 = '{}total = 0'.format(p)
    exec(code2)
    for i in eval(p):
        code3 = '{}total += i.contribution'.format(p)
        exec(code3)
```

一見うまくいくと思い喜んでいたのもつかの間、実際には変数をこの後のコードで参照しようとするとnot definedというエラーとなり、上記内にある変数からテンプレートにデータを運べないということで使えませんでした。

ググるとexec関数はそのような動きをするということは何となくわかったのですが、やはり無理なのでしょうか。実際にユーザーリストはかなりの数になるので何度も同じ内容を書くのはおっくうです。必ず簡単な方法があるのだと信じているのですが、良い方法があればご教示いただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願いします！

Comment: おそらく、`Eva_tour` とか `Eva_som` などという変数(オブジェクト)があると思うのですが、それらを事前に辞書型変数にまとめてしまう(例えば `Eva['tour'] = ...`, `Eva['som'] = ...`)と良いのではないでしょうか。そうすれば `Eva_all = {}; for k, v in Eva.items(): Eva_all[k] = v.objects.all() ...` の様に置き換えられると思うのですが。

Comment: 質問内容を見ると [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370) かもしれませんね。例えばこの辺の記事を参考に。[Django標準のUserモデルを使う](https://djangobrothers.com/tutorials/photo_app/user_model/), [Djangoユーザセッション管理機能を実装してみた。](https://sinyblog.com/django/user_session/), [Djangoで、ユーザー情報閲覧・更新ページ](https://narito.ninja/blog/detail/43/) 何か「同じ内容をユーザーごとに何度も書く」という発想は、Webアプリの一般的な作り方の知識に到達していなくて、pythonで目についた良さそうな機能にこだわってしまった感じがします。もっと手前の、何々をしたいけれどどうすれば/どこを探せば良いか、といった質問に戻った方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: 「ユーザーリスト」と書かれているものがいったい何なのか? が、実のところ回答者側にまったく伝わっていない質問になっています。

Comment: まさにご指摘のXY問題ですね。

Comment: kunif様、quiqui様、ご指摘有難うございます。
すみません、やろうとしていることですが ：
llistというリストがあります。これらはの中身はわかりやすく言えば人の名前で、これをユーザーリストと書きましたがDjangoのユーザーとは関係ありません。metropolis様ご察しのようにこれらの名前を含んだオブジェクトが別モジュール？にそれぞれあります。それらのオブジェクトリストをそれぞれ変数に渡して維持したい、そして、同時にその変数からオブジェクトの一部の値を総和したものを、さらに別の変数に渡す。これをllistリストをループで回して簡単に書きたいというのが意図です。
XY問題失礼しました。
metropolis様にアドバイスいただいた辞書型を試してみます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

辞書型変数やリストのリストを利用するというのがいまいちわからなかったのですが、ようやく理解できました。変数に代入するのではなく、リストに引数を入れていくという発想が全くありませんでした。下記のように書き直すとプログラム動きました。歓喜！
@metropolis 様、有難うございました、コメントが大きなヒントになりました。

```
Eva= [[],[],[]]
Eva[0] = Eva_tour.objects.all()
Eva[1] = Eva_som.objects.all()
Eva[2] = Eva_aim.objects.all()
totalscorelist = [0,0,0]
n = 0

for i in Eva:
    score = 0
    for j in i:
        score += j.contribution
    totalscorelist[n] = score
    n = n + 1
```

プログラミング、頭が活性化して、本当に面白いです。

Answer (score 0):

ご質問の意味はよく分かります。私も悩みました。
こんなのは如何でしょうか。

```
list = []

for n in range(3):

    sublist = []

    for i in range(3):

        sublist.append(n+i)

        print(sublist[i])

    list.append(sublist)

for n in range(3):

        print(list[n])
```